# typedef and malloc error in c(unknown srtuct type)

Tags: c

I have a following typedef in my C program which throws an error.This is part of my code-

```
typedef struct Room
{
    int ** values;
}Room;

int createRoom(Room pm) // it give me error unknown type Room
{
    //some code here
}

int main()
{
    Room *pm;
    pm=(Room)malloc(sizeof(Room));
    int n=callfun(pm);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me `unknown type Room error`. Also, I get an error in the malloc line.
Can anyone tell me where I am wrong

Comment: malloc doesn't need a cast and you casted to a wrong type.

Comment: Please copy and paste your exact code; what you have posted would not give "unknown type Room" .

Comment: I fixed that error of `unknown type room`.Now I am getting this error-
`incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function malloc`

Comment: you are missing the header file , please try stdlib.h

Comment: You need `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pm=(Room)malloc(sizeof(Room));
```

should be

```
pm=(Room *)malloc(sizeof(Room));
```

[Don't cast malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Just do

```
pm= malloc(sizeof(Room));
```

Comment: I fixed that error of `unknown type room`.Now I am getting this error-
`incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function malloc`

Comment: @Coder `#include<stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 pm=(Room)malloc(sizeof(Room));
```

Should be,

```
 pm=(Room*)malloc(sizeof(Room));
```

`pm` is `Room*`.

As stated in comment, as malloc return `void *` you need not to cast it, so it can be,

```
pm=malloc(sizeof(Room));
```

Comment: struct tags are a separate "space" to typenames in C

Comment: Separate space? You mean to say, name and variable of struct can be same?

Comment: The struct tag (the name just after `struct`) does not interfere with anything else